# Anything like bookmark notes plugin for netbeans?

Tags: plugins, netbeans, netbeans-7

Is there anything kind of a bookmarks notes plugin for netbeans that would allow me to write small notes on my bookmarks in the code ?

Answer (score 4):

It also included in NB7.2.

Switch to the bookmarks view. On the left side there is a toolbar-button like "Table View". A table of the the bookmarks with several columns "Name/Key/Location" will be opened. Doubleclick at a cell within the name column and you can create a note/alias for this bookmark.

Comment: I couldn't locate how to switch to bookmarks view. Could you guide me how to enable that ?

Comment: You can also bookmark the code and write notes as comment.

Answer (score 2):

Look at Netbeans plug-in page for [Scratch Pad](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/5349/scratch-pad), it does that but it has'nt been updated since NB 6, it looks kind of ugly, if the link its removed try to look there for another one, hope it helps.

Comment: This should have been in comment rather than answer section.

Comment: Not enought reputation :S